# Обработка файла с использованием буфера

Tags: c#, алгоритм, типы-данных, преобразование

Есть такой код:

```
void DeadSecCoding(string strfile)
    {
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfile, FileMode.Open,        FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite,1024*1024,true))
        using (BinaryReader sr = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            byte byte1;
            long nBytesRead = fs.Length;

                while (nBytesRead >0)
                {
                    byte1 = sr.ReadByte();

                    int i = Convert.ToInt32(byte1);

                    i *= 1234567;

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strfile+".mql",true))
                    {
                        writer.WriteAsync(i.ToString()+"@");
                    }  nBytesRead--;

                }
        }

    }
```

Его смысл: из потока читаем байт, конвертируем его в int, умножаем int на число, записываем в текстовый файл, преобразовывая int в string с добавление метки. Т.о.выходной файл имеет содержимое(обычный текст):

```
5372635@5272736@2437362@827463637@262627@
```

И так далее. Все записывается в одну строку.
Код работает очень медленно, т.к.постоянно открывается StreamWriter.
Как вынести запись в файл за пределы конструкции while таким образом, чтобы при преобразовании большого файла на входе не словить MemoryException?

Я думаю организовать некий промежуточный буфер, записывать туда 8*1024 int (или byte) и в цикле foreach делать запись через StreamWriter.

Может у кого есть идеи как реализовать нечто подобное или идеи как сделать лучше?

P.s. У меня есть кое-какие мысли, но хочется послушать чужое мнение. 
Спасибо!

Comment: `writer.WriteAsync` без `await` просто неправильно.

Comment: А сори, был await, потерялся при копировании :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int ReadBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
const int WriteBufferSize = 64 * 1024;

var readBuffer = new byte[ReadBufferSize];
var writeBuffer = new StringBuilder(WriteBufferSize);

using (var fs = new FileStream(strfile, FileMode.Open))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(strfile + ".mql", true))
{
    while (true)
    {
        writeBuffer.Clear();        
        int read = fs.Read(readBuffer, 0, ReadBufferSize);
        if (read == 0)
            break;

        for (int i = 0; i < read; ++i) {
            writeBuffer.Append((int)readBuffer[i] * 1234567);
            writeBuffer.Append('@');
        }

        sw.Write(writeBuffer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Узким местом в любом случае будет жесткий диск.

Comment: Главное чтобы памяти хватало. Через FileStream должны будут ходить файлы от 2Гб и выше.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
using (var infile = File.OpenRead(strfile))
using (var outfile = File.CreateText(strfile + ".mql"))
{
    var buf = new byte[65536];
    while (true)
    {
        var actuallyRead = infile.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            break;
        var results = buf.Take(actuallyRead)
                         .Select(b => ((int)b * 1234567).ToString() + "@");
        outfile.Write(string.Concat(results));
    }
}
```

---

Для `async`-варианта внутреннюю часть замените на:

```
        var actuallyRead = await infile.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            break;
        var results = buf.Take(actuallyRead)
                         .Select(b => ((int)b * 1234567).ToString() + "@");
        await outfile.WriteAsync(string.Concat(results));
```

Comment: А использование Select(b => ((int)b * 1234567).ToString() + "@"); сильно скажется на производительности?

Comment: @JackBlack: Не должно, узкое место у вас диск.

Answer (score 1):

Полез рыться в старые исходники, у себя же нашел еще реализацию:

```
void DeadSecCoding(string strfile) 
    {
       using (FileStream  fs = new FileStream(strfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
       using (StreamWriter  sw = new StreamWriter(strfile + ".dat", true))
       {

           long nBytesRead = fs.Length;
           int nBytesToRead = 0;

           for (int i = 0; i < nBytesRead; i++)
           {
               int nextByte = fs.ReadByte();

               nextByte *= 1234567;

               sw.Write(nextByte.ToString() + '~'); 
               nBytesToRead++;

           }
       }
       fs.Close();
  }
```

Потестировал его на больших входных данных - MemoryException не словил :-)
Нашел бы раньше и вопрос бы даже не возник